# Python throwing an SSL certificate validation error w/o consulting system CA bundles?

Tags: python, ssl, fedora-25

With two largely identical systems (both running Fedora 25, both with similar package versions installed), one system is failing with an SSL certicate verification error while another is not.  That is, if I run:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://insidehost.corp.example.com')
```

One one system it works, while on the other it fails:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)
```

At first I figure that I was simply missing the necessary CA certificates, but running python under `strace` reveals that on the failing system, python is *never attempting to open a ca bundle*.  That is, on the system that works:

```
strace -e trace=open,stat python testscript.py |& grep /etc/pki
```

Yields only:

```
open("/etc/pki/tls/legacy-settings", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=257079, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt", O_RDONLY) = 4
```

But on the failing system yields:

```
open("/etc/pki/tls/legacy-settings", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Furthermore, running the same test script with `python3` on the failing system...works!

In both cases, `python` is `/usr/bin/python` from `python-2.7.13-1.fc25.x86_64`.  Neither system is setting any `*_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable.

Comment: Hey -1 person, care to leave a comment? I think this is a pretty good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional investigation I've figured it out, and I thought I would post the solution here because it's not necessarily obvious.

The `requests` module includes its own certificate bundle, and it will fall back on that if it can't find another one to use.  The way it looks for a certificate bundle is like this, in requests/certs.py:

```
try:
    from certifi import where
except ImportError:
    def where():
        """Return the preferred certificate bundle."""
        # vendored bundle inside Requests
        return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'cacert.pem')
```

You can see the result of this by running:

```
$ python -m requests.certs
/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

As you can see from the above code, `requests` uses the `certifi` module to locate an appropriate bundle.  On the failing system, the `certifi` module had been installed via `pip` rather than using the system package, which meant it was lacking the appropriate configuration.

The solution was `yum install python2-certifi`.